# Concatenation of inner lists or ints

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, flatten

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but there it is...  I would like to go from:

```
lst = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2]
```

to:

```
output = [0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14, 2]
```

I can do this with a for loop such as:

```
output = []
for l in lst:
    if hasattr(l, '__iter__'):
        output.extend(l)
    else:
        output.append(l)
```

Maybe the for-loop is fine, but it feels like there should be a more elegant way to do this...  Trying to do this with numpy seems even more convoluted because ragged arrays aren't easily handled... so you can't (for example):

```
output = np.asanyarray(lst).flatten().tolist()
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here's my comparison between the two methods provided by @T.J and @Ashwini - thanks to both!

```
In [5]: %paste
from itertools import chain
from collections import Iterable
lis = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2]
def solve(lis):
    for x in lis:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring):
            yield x
        else:
            yield [x]

%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(solve(lis)))

%timeit [a for x in lis for a in (x if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x,basestring) else [x])]
## -- End pasted text --
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 us per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.12 us per loop
```

**Update2:**

```
...
lis = lis *10**5
%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(solve(lis)))

%timeit [a for x in lis for a in (x if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x,basestring) else [x])]
## -- End pasted text --
1 loops, best of 3: 699 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 698 ms per loop
```

Comment: ...or for irregular lists, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python).

Comment: Yup, sure is - apologies for the dup, didn't think to search 'flatten' :/

Comment: Probably because (on Python 2.x) you can just do `from compiler.ast import flatten; flatten([[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2])` -> `[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14, 2]`

Comment: Change the list size before timing the solutions: `lis = lis *10**5`,
`itertools.chain` is faster than normal list comprehension for bigger size list, for small lists timings doesn't matter.

Comment: Very good point - looks like `lis=lis *10**5` is pretty much the tipping point between the two methodologies.

Comment: @blazetopher well that's weird, itertools.chain is faster for moderate number of items too. And in-fact it is preferred over normal list comprehension for flattening a list. see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/408281/846892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty straightforward approach that uses a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2]
>>> [a for x in data for a in (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])]
[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14, 2]
```

Here are timing comparisons, it looks like my version is slightly faster (note that I modified my code to use `collections.Iterable` as well to make sure the comparison is fair):

```
In [9]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(solve(data)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.22 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit [a for x in data for a in (x if isinstance(x, Iterable) else [x])]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.45 us per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I was very close to this myself (not posted) but wasn't getting the logic portion correct.  Do you know if this is more/less performant than @Ashwini's response?

Comment: @blazetopher Just added a timing comparison.

Comment: Don't use `input` as a variable name.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Good point, thanks!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Agreed, silly oversight on my part

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain` like this:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Iterable
>>> lis = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2]
def solve(lis):
    for x in lis:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring):
            yield x
        else:
            yield [x]
...             

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(solve(lis)))
[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14, 2]
```

Works fine for strings too:

```
>>> lis = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], "234"]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(solve(lis)))
[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14, '234']
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> lis = lis *(10**4)
#modified version of FJ's answer that works for strings as well
>>> %timeit [a for x in lis for a in (x if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x,basestring) else [x])]
10 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(solve(lis)))
1 loops, best of 3: 98.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution.  Any idea if this is more/less performant than @F.J's answer?

Comment: @blazetopher FJ's solution is going to be faster as he's using a list comprehension , I used a function to make the solution more readable.
And my solution also handles the case if strings are present in the data.

Comment: benefits to both methods!  Thanks again!

Comment: @blazetopher have a look at my updated solution.

Comment: Intriguing that your timeit results are different than @T.J's, I'm editing my post to show my comparison

Comment: @blazetopher note that I've modified FJ's solution to handle strings as well.

Comment: @AshwaniChaudhary - yes, thank you.  When I run the timeit comparison, the comprehension comes out slightly faster for me for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

You can Use generator to make list consist of iterables only

```
((i if isinstance(i,Iterable) else [i])
```

And then use any of following methods to concatenate them into one list:

would You try `sum`

```
from collections import Iterable
lis = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2]
sum(((i if isinstance(i,Iterable) else [i]) for i in lis), [])
```

You should provide initial value for sum `[]` to start sum from

or `itertools.chain()`
but in this case You should unpack Your upper-level list into set of lists

```
import itertools
lis = [[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 11, 12], [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 14], 2]
list(itertools.chain(*((i if isinstance(i,Iterable) else [i]) for i in lis)))
```

or just list comprehension

```
[a for x in input for a in (x if isinstance(x, Iterable) else [x])]
```

But One should mind that strings are iterable as well. And If there will be string on upper level it would be spited into chars.

Comment: Your methods will work only if all the items of `lis` are iterable.

Comment: You are righ I should care of this